Can this problem reduce to the SIS problem or LWE problem?
The description of the graceless problem is as below.
Given a full rank square matrix $A=(R\cdot S+E)\in\mathbb{Z}_q^{n\times n}$,where:

$q>2^\lambda$ is a prime;
$R\leftarrow\mathbb{Z}_q^{n\times n}$ is a full rank random matrix, the effect of the martix $R$ is to randomize the $S$ matrix;
$S\leftarrow\mathbb{Z}_q^{n\times n}$ is a singular matrix, thus it has a vector $\vec{s}\in\ker(S)$ s.t. $S\cdot\vec{s}=0$,
-- in which the low/upper value bound of non-zero/one entries in the vector $\vec{s}$ is $2^{\frac{\lambda}{4}}\leq s_{i}\leq2^{\frac{3\lambda}{8}}$, only one entry in $\vec{s}$ is one, and the other entries are zero;
The matrix $E\in\mathbb{Z}_q^{n\times n}$,its each entry $0\leq e_j\leq2^{\frac\lambda 8}$.

The problem is that, only given $(A,n,q)$ and the value range of ${s_i},{e_j}$, it is hard to find a vector $\vec{s^{\prime}}$,such that $\|A\cdot\vec{s^{\prime}}\|_\infty\leq\|E\cdot\vec{s}\|_\infty.$
Considering the simplest $\vec{s}=(s_1,1,0,...,0)$, $2^{\frac{\lambda}{4}}\leq s_1 \leq2^{\frac{3\lambda}{8}}$, if $\lambda$ is large, e.g., $\lambda=512$, whether the problem is hard? if yes, can it reduce to well-studied problems, such as LWE, or SIS?
I think the problem is easy when there is no restriction on the form of $\vec{s'}$. If we constrain the form of $\vec{s'}$ to be the form of $\vec{s}$, I guess the problem is hard.
Intuitively, I think the problem is irrelevant with SIS or LWE, a direct attack is to try all possible $s'_1\in[2^{\frac{\lambda}{4}},2^{\frac{3\lambda}{8}}]$ and check whether the condition $\|A\cdot\vec{s^{\prime}}\|_\infty\leq\|E\cdot\vec{s}\|_\infty$ holds, where $\vec{s'}=(s'_1,1,0,...,0)$.

Is there a reason to write out $R\cdot S$ if both $R, S$ are secret? Or do you intend to give $R$ to an adversary as well? It is also worth mentioning that "full rank" is really only precisely defined when $\mathbb{Z}_q$ is a field, e.g. when $q$ is prime. For composite $q$ a typical other condition is that the linear map $R: \mathbb{Z}_q^n\to\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ surjects.

You can have maps $R$ that fail to surject, but do not have zero determinant (a typical way to say "not full rank"). For example, $R = 2I_n$ as a map from $\mathbb{Z}{10}^n\to\mathbb{Z}{10}^n$ has determinant $2^n$, which is non-zero (even $\bmod 10$), but fails to surject as its image is even.

Also, I don't understand the distinction between $\vec{s'}, \vec{s}$, and $S$.

@MarkSchultz-Wu Thanks for your response. According to your comments, I modified the question to further be clear. $S$ is a random singular matrix as described, and  $\vec{s}$ is a vector with the form of $({0}^l,{s_i}{i\in[m]},1,{0}^{n-m-1-l})\in \mathbb{Z}^n$, where $l$ denotes the number of the first zeros in front of ${s_i}{i\in[m]}$, $m$ refers to the number of $s_i\in[\mathrm{FixedRange}]$. for instance, if $l=0,m=1,n=4$, then $\vec{s}=(s_1,1,0,0)$; or if $l=1,m=1,n=4$, $\vec{s}=(0,s_1,1,0)$. The goal of adversary is to find a $\vec{s'}$, s.t. meeting the condition metioned.
